# Handling Logstash Plugin Filter errors gracefully

Tags: exception, logstash, elastic-stack

So, I'm building a plugin for logstash and I can't seem to find any documentation on how I should handle exceptions thrown and or rescued. So far, and similar to grok, we're adding a `event["tag"] = ["_filter_error"]`, but in regards to metadata like a stacktrace, error type, etc... where should those live, or should they be omitted?

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a case-by-case question, so admittedly hard to answer. But I'll share how we ended up doing it so it might help someone.

1. Rescue all the exceptions (LogStash will hang otherwise)
2. Add a tag to the event `event["tags"] = ["_filter_error"]` so these can be  query-able down the road
3. Ignore the stacktrace and error message (our decision - basically use the tag instead)
4. Use a single field as metadata about the tag we added to the event. For instance, if our filter blew up altogether, honey-badger it and move on. If our filter failed 1/2 through filtering, add as much data to the event as you can, add the tag in step 2, then create a metadata field (i.e. `event["unknown_tags"] = [1,6,7]` where our filter blew up at tags 1,6,7 but passed for everything else)